# MarkoJS for loop over array of objects

Tags: node.js, koa, knex.js, koa-router, marko

I really need help with a pretty simple and trivial problem, but here it goes. I am using marko on the server side in NodeJS and am rendering my views via:

```
ctx.render({
});
```

with koa-router and koa. I need help in the html dept on how to go about for or while looping over all these to display via:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried and tried and tried, but am too frustrated to move on, please someone save me as it feels like a Monday brain fart on a Thursday -_-

```
"invoices": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customer_id": 1,
        "line_items_total": 187,
        "additional_fees": 10,
        "tax_rate": 0.07,
        "sub_total": 210.79
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "customer_id": 4,
        "line_items_total": 100,
        "additional_fees": 0,
        "tax_rate": 0.07,
        "sub_total": 107
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "customer_id": 2,
        "line_items_total": 48.4,
        "additional_fees": 0,
        "tax_rate": 0.07,
        "sub_total": 51.79
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "customer_id": 9,
        "line_items_total": 286,
        "additional_fees": 35,
        "tax_rate": 0.07,
        "sub_total": 343.47
    }
]
```

The full project file is at: [GitHub](http://www.github.com/bRRRITSCOLD/koa-knex)

This is under:

```
/routes/invoices/invoices.js
```

and the query can be found in:

```
/db/queries
```

which refers to:

```
queries.objects.getAllObjects()
```

in:

```
/routes/invoices/invoices.js
```

Comment: Hey, it's me again, just noticed the comment that you left me on that deleted question and I wanted to let you know that it wasn't me who DV your post (And nobody can DV a post twice BTW). Sorry about that, but it wasn't me - I did upvote this one however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can loop over arrays using the following syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li for(invoice in data.invoices)>${invoice}</li>
</ul>
```

Marko also allows you to loop over the properties of an object if you need to do that as well:

```
<ul>
    <li for(invoice in data.invoices)>
            <ul>
                <li for(key,value in invoice)>
                    <strong>${key}</strong>: ${value}
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For reference: https://markojs.com/docs/core-tags/#codeltforgtcode

Answer (score 0):

L-O-L got it, for anyone referencing this in the future, a nice simple:

```
invoices.marko
```

file to get a basic understanding. Of course I could:

```
${invoice.id}
${invoice.customer_id}
${invoice.line_items_total}
${etc}
```

to list out each individual attribute/property/value of the desired .key

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Invoices</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li for(invoice in data.invoices)>${invoice}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```